# How to determine whether a point lies on Quad2DCurve

Tags: bezier

I have successfully drawn a Quad2D or Bezier curve in java. I have the equation for the same. But I need to determine whether a particular point(x,y) lies on the curve or not. I tried using Quad2D.contains and a few GeneralPath APIs, I could not get the result accurately.

Can someone help to find out the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've meant QuadCurve2D class, which is quadratic Bezier curve.
There seems to be no ready-made method for that, and the problem comes to the distance from the point to the Bezier curve.
Let's P0 will be your point, `P1` is a start point, `P2` - a control point and `P3` is an end point of your curve.
Then point on the curve will be given by

```
P = B(t)
```

There is such `t`, for which distance between `P` and `P0` will be minimal.

```
F(t) = (B(t)_x - P0_x)^2 + (B(t)_y - P0_y)^2 -> min
```

If distance is 0 or less than certain error, then P0 is on the curve.
t can be found with Netwon's iterative method by minimizing cost function

```
t_n = t_n-1 + F'(t) / F''(t)
```

where `F'` is first derivative of cost function and `F''` is its second derivative.

```
F'(t) = 2 * (B(t)_x - P0_x) * B'(t)_x + 2 * (B(t)_y - P0_y) * B'(t)_y
F''(t) = 2 * B'(t)_x * B'(t)_x + 2 * (B(t)_x - P0_x) * B''(t)_x +
         2 * B'(t)_y * B'(t)_y + 2 * (B(t)_y - P0_x) * B''(t)_y
```

First derivative of quadratic Bezier curve B'(t) is a line segment with a start point `(P2 - P1)` and end point `(P3 - P2)`. Second derivative `B''(t)` is a point `P3 - 2 * P2 + P1`.

Plugging everything together will give a formula to `t` for which `F(t)` is minimal.